# Add a threshold to starboard for discord bot

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

So far I got the bot to add the message to a specific channel when the `⭐` reaction is triggered. I am stuck now... I'm trying to add a threshold where it takes a certain amount of `⭐` reactions to trigger the push the specific channel. Any help will be greatly apperciated.

```
    const handleStarboard = async  () => {
        const starboard = bot.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name.toLowerCase() === 'starboard');
        const msgs = await starboard.messages.fetch({ limit: 100 });
        const existingMsg = msgs.find(msg =>
            msg.embeds.length === 1 ?
            (msg.embeds[0].footer.text.startsWith(reaction.message.id) ? true : false) : false);
        if(existingMsg) existingMsg.edit(`${reaction.count} - ⭐`);
        else {
            const embed = new MessageEmbed()
                .setAuthor(reaction.message.author.tag, reaction.message.author.displayAvatarURL())
                .addField('Url', reaction.message.url)
                .setDescription(reaction.message.content)
                .setFooter(reaction.message.id + ' - ' + new Date(reaction.message.createdTimestamp));
                

            if(starboard)
                starboard.send('1 - ⭐', embed);
        }
    }
    if(reaction.emoji.name === '⭐') {
        if(reaction.message.channel.name.toLowerCase() === 'starboard') return;
        if(reaction.message.partial) {
            await reaction.fetch();
            await reaction.message.fetch();
            handleStarboard();
        }
        else
            handleStarboard();
    }
});

bot.on('messageReactionRemove', async (reaction, user) => {
    const handleStarboard = async () => {
        const starboard = bot.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name.toLowerCase() === 'starboard');
        const msgs = await starboard.messages.fetch({ limit: 100 });
        const existingMsg = msgs.find(msg =>
        msg.embeds.length === 1 ?
            (msg.embeds[0].footer.text.startsWith(reaction.message.id) ? true : false) : false);
        if(existingMsg) {
            if(reaction.count === 0)
                existingMsg.delete({ timeout: 2500 });
            else
                existingMsg.edit(`${reaction.count} - ⭐`)
        };
    }
    if(reaction.emoji.name === '⭐') {
        if(reaction.message.channel.name.toLowerCase() === 'starboard') return;
        if(reaction.message.partial) {
            await reaction.fetch();
            await reaction.message.fetch();
            handleStarboard();
        }
        else
            handleStarboard();
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you please provide more info than 'you are stuck'? What is happening with that code that’s wrong? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: No I’m not getting any errors at all just takes 1 reaction to send it to the starboard. I want that to be 3 star reactions before it pushes. Sorry about the confusion.